# How to convert cookie string from allHTTPHeaderFields to HTTPCookie

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check if cookie.name=='Custom' exists in a request.

Right now I reading the string from dictionary `request.allHTTPHeaderFields` and then doing split then follow it by for loop. I think there is a much elegant way.

```
if let allHTTPHeaderFields = request.allHTTPHeaderFields,
   let cookies = allHTTPHeaderFields["Cookie"] {
   let cookieArray = cookies.split(separator: ";")
       for cookie in cookieArray {
           if cookie.contains("Custom") {
             //do something
           }
        }
}
```

I tried `HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: allHTTPHeaderFields, for: url)` but it is returning `0 elements` always

Comment: `if cookieArray.contains(where: { $0.contains("Custom")}) { //Do something}`?

Comment: I could avoid the for loop now. Thanks.

Comment: That's still doing a loop I guess (inner & hidden code of its implementation). It just doing a `break` (it stop when condition is met). It may be more readable though.

Comment: I know but the code is cleaner